# Update panel end request method

Tags: javascript, updatepanel

In an ASP.NET web application I have an update panel which has a button, when pressed it is doing some data processing which will take time up-to 10 mins. during this process I am showing loading screen. the issue that I am facing is that once this data processing is completed the end-request JavaScript method for update panel is not getting called in IE after the server-side code is executed. where as in chrome and other browsers it is working as expected.

Any pointers why IE is behaving like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 in IE to open Developer Tool, Perform the action. See console tab if any error is there in IE.

Comment: Thank you for your Response. I have done these, there are no errors being reported in the Console.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explorer I even tried to change the KeepAliveTimeout as suggested in this link but it did not work.